# OPA5: How to make sure that every test starts in a fresh environment?

Tags: sapui5

I got to refactor a module of [OPA5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/2696ab50faad458f9b4027ec2f9b884d.html)-tests, because most of the test-cases fail currently.
While trying to find the reason for the failing I found out that most of the tests aren't erroneous.

When you run them in isolation they work just fine. The problem occurs when you run them as a module. This means you run them as a group. One test after the other.

The problem occurs when **one** test fails. Normally you execute [`iTeardownMyAppFrame()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.test.Opa5/methods/iTeardownMyAppFrame) as
**the very last** method of the test. To remove the used iFrame. So that the following test
finds an untouched environment in which it can run.

Now when a test fails at some line, then the test stops, and the following invocations aren't done.
`iTeardownMyAppFrame` is never executed and the following test starts in the environment of the previous (the failed) test. So it might fail too because the environment isn't as expected.

**Is there a way to make sure that every test starts in a new iFrame?**

Something like "try-finally" with the `iTeardownMyAppFrame` in the final block. So that it
is executed in any case. No matter if the test has worked or it has failed.

Comment: Can't you catch the error the failed test throws and handle the iTeardownMyAppFrame in the catch statment ?

Comment: You need a more flexible test runner for this. Wdio does an excellent job. you need a real webdriver to manipulate the browser state